# Images uploads src url are disappearing after refresh in tinyMCE

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce

My tinyMCE editor was made in codeigniter in admin main js file, currently the images is showing in the tinyMCE editor with link blob:htt-ps://mysite.com/94d8r54t6afe-032f-45ea-9574-9d4348fea70504 but once it is saved, it shows just a box without src url the code is:

```
 tinymce.init({
        selector: '.tinymce',
        theme: "modern",
        skin: "custom",


    plugins: [
        "image code",
        "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ],

  toolbar: "  insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | code | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor",

      image_title: true, 

      automatic_uploads: true,

      file_picker_types: 'file image media',

      file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

        input.onchange = function() {
          var file = this.files[0];
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function () {
            var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
            var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
            var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
            var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
            blobCache.add(blobInfo);

            // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
            cb(blobInfo.blobUri(),{ title: file.name });
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };

        input.click();
      }


    });
```

I also added the upload like this:

```
images_upload_url: '/admin/uploader/',

images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
    var xhr, formData;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.open('POST', '/admin/uploader/');

    xhr.onload = function() {
        var json;

        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
            return;
        }

        json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
            failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
            return;
        }
        console.log(json);  
        success(json.location);
    };

    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

    xhr.send(formData);
},
```

> what to do here? any suggestion to show the image and not just a box without src url link?

**UPDATE:**

> fixed the error, now I can upload now the images even after
>   refreshing, I just change the json path into:

```
  success("../../../"+json.location);
```

now the only problem is, every time the user uploading image the images are saved at /uploads/ folder, but if the user change the image another image will be saved and the other image before will be kipped, how to delete the other images that inserted before that is not currently used in the editor?

Comment: you upload on server with tinymcem then you can use `images_upload_handler`

Comment: yes I did, but same error

Comment: and you returning uploaded file url in location variable ?

Comment: I fixed it by adding first directory to my json   success("../../../"+json.location);   now my only problem is that the images are still there if you delete the image in the editor, how to delete it also to the image containing folder when you delete it to the editor?

Comment: hi, @alvz I'm also facing same issue, can you please tell me how to fix it success("../../../"+json.location); is not working for me